# Best way to pull Location header from RestResponse

Tags: c#, .net, rest, http, http-headers

What's the best way to pull the server location from the RestResponse object?

```
$"{RestResponse.Server}/{RestResponse.Request.Resource}"
```

or

```
RestResponse.ResponseUri
```

What I need is the place where I sent the request to, including the resource.
Thanks

Comment: Show us your attempts

Comment: Added/editted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used RestResponse.ResponseUri in the end since I knew that my response Uri was the same one that I sent my request to, so it fit my purposes fine. I couldn't find a proper reference to the request Uri.

If someone else answers this better I will update the accepted answer.